# Facebook Graph API - Get user profile from conversations

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

by using **Facebook Graph API** I can fetch the conversations between users and my page. One of the returned conversations looks like this:

```
{
  "message": "message content",
  "from": {
    "name": "My Page's Name",
    "email": "198301820627381@facebook.com",
    "id": "198301820627381",
  },
  "to": {
    "data": [
      {
        "name": "John Doe",
        "email": "396169264164870@facebook.com",
        "id": "396169264164870",
      }
    ]
  },
  "id": "m_mid.$cAADurJ0X8UhnJ3tfxVg9jYXJW5fp"
}
```

I see that I got the user's `id` field. How can I fetch this user's profile (first name, last name, profile pic) base on this field ? (or is there another way ?)
I followed the [Graph API's User Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/) but all I got are the user's `id` and `name` (which I already have from the returned conversation).

Comment: What else would you need?

Comment: Thanks @WizKid ! I updated my question. What I want to get are the user first name, last name and profile pic. They are mentioned in the `fields` section in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

profile_pic only works for PSIDs (Messenger bot events), for ASIDs just use the picture field instead